# Yes/No : Does $MM^T $ have rank $ r$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let  $M$ be  an $n \times n $ matrix with rank $r$.
>
> Then which of the  following statements is true ?
>
> $1).$ If $M $ has real entries, then $MM^T$ necessarily has rank $r$
>
> $2).$ If $M$ has complex entries, then  $MM^T$ necessarily has rank $ r$

Note : Here $M^T $ denotes the transpose of $M$

### My attempt:

I know  every real matrix is complex matrix, so both are true. I mean both option $1$ and $2 $ are true.

Comment: (1) "Fat people are bad at sports". (2) "People are bad at sports". Since every fat person is a person, my guess is that both of these sentences are true.

Comment: It helps to know that if $M$ is a matrix with real entries then $M^T$ and $M M^T$ have the same null space. Proof: $M^T x = 0 \implies M M^T x = 0 \implies x^T M M^T x = 0 \implies \| M^T x\|^2 = 0 \implies M^T x = 0$.

Comment: A student logic solution: if 2) is true then both are true, if 1) is wrong then both are wrong. It would be weird to have both true/false so easily (the teacher is certainly testing some kind of finer knowledge). Then one should be true and one wrong. Hence, 1) is true and 2) is false.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For 2, consider e.g. $M=\pmatrix{1&-i\\i&1}$ of rank $1$.
$$MM^T=\pmatrix{1&-i\\i&1} \pmatrix{1&i\\-i&1}=\pmatrix{0&0\\0&0} $$